# How to setup CORS for handlers and Class Based Views in the same application

Tags: python, cors, aiohttp

**Goal**: 
I am trying to setup CORS for resources in aiohttp based web application using aiohttp_cors library. My app has a number of routes some of which are just usual coroutines, but some are [Class Based Views](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#class-based-views) (We are moving to Class Based Views but for now it is in mixed state). For CORS setup i refer to aiohttp and aiohttp-cors docs.

**Problem**:
When accessing `/api/v1/users` i am getting an empty response with this stacktrace on server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 410, in start
     await resp.prepare(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_response.py", line 299, in prepare
     await request._prepare_hook(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 712, in _prepare_hook
     await app.on_response_prepare.send(self, response)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/signals.py", line 35, in send
     await receiver(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp_cors/cors_config.py", line 157, in _on_response_prepare
     config = self._router_adapter.get_non_preflight_request_config(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp_cors/urldispatcher_router_adapter.py", line 315, in get_non_preflight_request_config
     request, request.method)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp_cors/mixin.py", line 23, in get_request_config
     raise ValueError("aiohttp-cors is not configured.")
```

**Coroutine handlers**

```
# /api/role.py
from models import Role
from aiohttp.web_response import json_response


class RoleHandler:

    def register(self, app):
        app.router.add_get('/roles', self.get_roles)

    @classmethod
    async def get_roles(cls, request):
        roles = await Role.select_roles()
        return json_response(dict(roles=roles))
```

**Class-Based View**

```
# user.py
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_cors import CorsViewMixin
from models import User

class UsersCollectionView(web.View, CorsViewMixin):

    async def get(self):
        users = await User.select_users()
        return web.json_response(dict(users=users))
```

**Main**

```
# main.py
from auth_service.api.role import RoleHandler
from auth_service.api.user import UsersCollectionView


def create_app(config, *, loop=None):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    app = Application()
    api_v1_app = Application()

    # Register all handlers
    role_handler = RoleHandler()
    role_handler.register(api_v1_app)
    api_v1_app.router.add_view('/users', UsersCollectionView)

    app.add_subapp('/api/v1', api_v1_app)
    app['api_v1'] = api_v1_app
    cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app, defaults={
            "*": aiohttp_cors.ResourceOptions(
                allow_credentials=True,
                expose_headers="*",
                allow_methods="*",
                allow_headers="*",
                max_age=3600
            )
        })
        for route in app.router.routes():
            logger.info(f'Adding cors to {route.method} {route.handler}')
            cors.add(route)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Config.from_environ()
    logger.info('Loaded config %r', config)
    app = create_app(config)
    run_app(app, port=config.server.port)
```

**What I tried**:

- Accessing `/api/v1/roles` (coroutine handler) works as expected
- Accessing any api route works as expected if I remove CORS setup code
- Setting up cors on `api_v1_app` sub-application instance does not resolve the problem

I have no clue how to proceed with troubleshooting. Would like to know if this is even a supported scenario for `aiohttp-cors` plugin in general and if yes than what am i missing.

Comment: It seems like this is a bug in aiohttp-cors library. CORS configuration that was defined on main web.Application does not apply properly on a sub-application resource - https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-cors/issues/219.